# C++ Avoiding excessive use of lock() in member functions that use boost::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have an abstract base class called `Curve`. There are three classes that inherit from it:
- `SingleCurve`
- `MultiCurve`
- `CurveShift`, which "shifts" anything that derives from `Curve` (takes a `boost::shared_ptr<Curve>` in its constructor)

I have a repository in memory that keeps track of all the curves, let's call it `CurveStore`. It is implemented as a singleton with a `std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Curve> >` inside of it.

My problem is with `CurveShift`. I want to use a `boost::weak_ptr` to reference the underlying `Curve` it is shifting. This way, should the underlying `Curve` go away, the `CurveShift` will not be able to get a `lock()` and I will know that the `CurveShift` is invalid. The problem is that in the naive implementation of `CurveShift`, where you try to get a `lock()` every time you access one of the member functions, it degrades performance significantly. Is there a standard way/"pattern" to avoid having to do a `lock()` in all the member functions?

Comment: You can check `expired()` instead of attempting the lock.

Comment: Does it really make sense to have a `CurveShift` without any underlying `Curve`? Why not store a `shared_ptr` directly rather than the `weak_ptr`? That way whether the original reference to the curve is alive or not, your `CurveShift` is still a valid *curve* (note that if it is not, then the Liskov substitution principle would be broken, as a `CurveShift` is only a `Curve` when the underlying `Curve` has not been released) Additionally, why do the functions take `shared_ptr`'s? Do they store copies of the object? If not, consider passing references rather than smart pointers.

Comment: Kerrek: If I want to use the CurveShift member functions, I have to get a lock at some point, there is no way around it. Knowing that the underlying Curve is valid isn't enough, I have to use it.

Comment: David: I don't know why I wrote initially that functions use `shared_ptr`'s, the actually do use references. As for why I am not using `shared_ptr`'s for the underlying `Curve`, that's because of the `CurveStore`. If the underlying `Curve` is refreshed in the store, I want the `CurveShift` to be invalidated. That way I avoid accidental use of stale `CruveShift`'s.

Comment: @Hazerider: What if the code tries to use a stale `CurveShift`, what would happen? It detects that the underlying curve has been removed, and fails? How? The problem at that point is that you have what is seemingly a valid object (`CurveShift` but the object is not valid anymore and cannot be used as a `Curve` anywhere as it will fail, so that is breaking the Liskov substitution principle: the derived type can be used as a base *sometimes* but not *always*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pattern" would be "external/internal functions" (not an official name), where the external functions (public), lock the weak_ptr's and the internal functions (private) take a shared_ptr& as parameter.  This only helps if you have a lean interface that actually lets the object do something (not a getter/setter interface)

Comment: Do you think it would be reasonable to achieve this by having both a `weak_ptr` and a `shared_ptr` in the `CurveShift` class? When the original `CurveShift` is put into the store, I manually release the `shared_ptr` via some member function. On copy construction, I would get a `lock` and assign it to the `shared_ptr` member. When the copy of the `CurveShift` object goes out of scope, the `shared_ptr` goes away and I am left with the original number of references.

Comment: @Hazerider: to me it is more natural to pass it around as parameter.  When you cache it as member variable, you have to make sure that you reset it when finished.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is with `CurveShift`. I want to use a `boost::weak_ptr` to reference the underlying `Curve` it is shifting. This way, should the underlying `Curve` go away, the `CurveShift` will not be able to get a `lock()` and I will know that the `CurveShift` is invalid.

Very strange, and weak, design. (But most designs based on weak_something are strange, and weak.)

Do you really want this weak behaviour?

I suggest that you change your design to not have null `CurveShift` object: whenever a `Curve` is destroyed, remove all objects that depend on it. This way, you don't need any `weak_ptr`.

Comment: Your suggestion is not really relevant in multi-threaded environments. In that case, I would have to deal with locks anyway, so I might as well use weak_ptr. Perhaps it might make things clearer if I mentioned that this whole infrastructure is used from within Excel. I need to be careful about underlying Curves and CurveShifts, as depending on how the spreadsheet is designed,  it affects the dependency tree and lifetime of objects.